# Apache and Nginx

Tags: apache2, 20.04

I want to run both Apache2 and Nginx  on the same server, how do I do this? I am running Ubuntu 20.04 server, I am installing iredmail for my server and I want to use this and run my website at the same time.

Comment: First thing you should do is make sure your webservers are running on different ports (default port for http is :80, and for https it's :443). The webserver that will be displaying the actual webpage should remain on the default ports.

Comment: Now that I got iRedMail working when I goto the admin panel I see

Comment: Ok I first need to get https://askubuntu.com/questions/1260943/after-installing-iredmail-i-see-a-502-error fixed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just check this tutorial, there's everything explained regarding your question
to setup and configure ngxinx and apache2
https://websiteforstudents.com/setup-nginx-reverse-proxy-apache2-ubuntu-17-04-17-10/

It's an older version of ubuntu, but I think there should be no difference.

Here the installation scripts of it:

## Install Nginx

```
sudo apt-get update && apt-get install nginx

sudo systemctl start nginx.service
sudo systemctl enable nginx.service
```

## Install Apach2

```
sudo apt-get install apache2
```

## Nginx Config for IredMail

https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/recipes/iredmail/

Like mention in the comment by @hextex, we need to know the port of your webserver to configure it correctly for nginx.

## Nginx to configure multiple webpages

https://webdock.io/en/docs/how-guides/how-configure-nginx-to-serve-multiple-websites-single-vps

I hope this helps.